# Google Analytics won't show behavior flow completely

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have analytics for my site, but in "*Behavior Flow*" i won't be able to see all the data and it only shows "*Starting Page*" and not "*1st Interaction*" and ...

I searched through internet and i didn't find any solutions. Some said i should turn off grouping data, but i didn't find it in "*Admin*" on Analytics.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Error Image]

This is my content page

[Content Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zliGv.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots of your "content" report, want to see what your page urls look like.

Comment: I added my content page to the post
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because your site never goes further levels down past the root. All of your pages are /p?parameter=value.

To fix this, you need to create either virtual pages or change the CMS setup so that your urls are something like /level1/level2/level3/level4page